# can we use wildcards at class level in java

Tags: java, generics

I tried using wildcards at class level and I'm getting the following errors

```
 Test.java:3: error: <identifier> expected
class Test1<? extends Object,Cloneable,Serializable>
            ^
Test.java:3: error: '{' expected
class Test1<? extends Object,Cloneable,Serializable>
                            ^
```

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Think about it - why would you do this? How would you use that type information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

From [`Wiki of WildCard`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_(Java))

> The wildcard ? in Java is a special actual parameter for the instantiation of generic (parameterized) types. It can be used for the instantiation, not in the definition of a generic unit.

Answer (score 6):

It actually wouldn't make sense to use a wildcard in a class definition.

for example:

```
class MyClass<T extends MyInterface>
```

You need that T, You'll use it inside your class in things like members `private T myT` or methods `void doIt(T t)`.

What would be the point having a generic type that you can't use?

Wildcard generics are Java's way to handle [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science))

Answer (score 4):

No, We cannot use Wildcards at the class level.

Syntax below is not allowed:

```
1. class A<?>{}
2. class A<? extends Number>{}
3. new ArrayList<?>();
4. ArrayList<?> al5=new ArrayList<?>();
5. ArrayList<? extends Number> al9=new ArrayList<?>();
```

Allowed are:

```
1.ArrayList<?> al=new ArrayList<String>();
2.ArrayList<?> al2=new ArrayList();
3.ArrayList<? extends Runnable> al3=new ArrayList();
4.ArrayList<? super Runnable> al4=new ArrayList();
5.ArrayList<? super Runnable> al5=new ArrayList<Object>();
6.ArrayList<? super Runnable> al6=new ArrayList<Runnable>();
7.ArrayList<? extends Runnable> al7=new ArrayList<Runnable>();
8.ArrayList<? extends Runnable> al8=new ArrayList<Thread>();
9.ArrayList<? extends Object> al9=new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says add `<identifier>` 
so instead of ? replace with for example T
For Example:

```
class Test1<T extends Object,Cloneable,Serializable>
```

because with Class you need to add some identifier, unlike methods!