# Boundmismatch error when declaring a variable of a type defined in a generic class

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, bounds

Class is defined as `Header<Field<Column<Content<?>>>>{}`, variable declaration is `Header<Field<Column<Content<String>>>> aHeader`. This gives a BoundMismatch error. Changing declaration to `Header<Field<Column<Content<?>>>> aHeader`; removes the error but loses type information and therefore not desired. What is the strategy to make this work? PS: The class definition has to retain the ?.

Comment: What do you mean "loses type information"?  It doesn't look like you're losing anything.  Anyway, the short answer is, you can't.  Because a `Column<Content<String>>` simply _isn't_ a `Column<Content<?>>`, even though it seems like it should be.

Comment: What do you mean "loses type information"? . . . If i instantiated Content<?> someCont=Content<String>(); then i did someCont.getContent(); I would get Object, not String.

Answer (score 0):

A variable of type `Header<Field<Column<Content<String>>>>` Can only ever contain a `Header<Field<Column<Content<String>>>>` It has no upper or lower bounds, it can only contain `Header<Field<Column<Content<String>>>>`

`Header<Field<Column<Content<?>>>>` Represents a `Header<Field<Column<Content<**unknown**>>>>`

How can you be sure that when you fetch the string back from the unknown variant, that you will always get a string? You can't. Therefore you get the error above to warn you that you can not assign a wildcard collection to a string.

Collections are both producers, and consumers.

As a general rule of thumb, [PECS: Producers Extend, Consumers Supers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Which is a mnemonic device to remember the bounds.

However a Collection acts as both, it can have things added as well as popped. So, generally they are restricted to a single type.

**Can you add a string to a collection of ?**

No. the wildcard is a type restriction saying it could be a collection of any type. It does NOT mean that it can *contain* every type.

**So what are wildcards good for?**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Shows some good examples, They can be used to restrict the types of the collection itself, as opposed to defining the collection as able to take any object.

e.g.

```
public void addRectangle(List<? extends Shape> shapes) {
    // Compile-time error!
    shapes.add(0, new Rectangle());
}
```

Is a compile error, because the only guarantee you have, is that shapes is a collection of things that extend Shape, it could be a `List<Circle>`!

Where as

```
public void addRectangle(List<Shape> shapes) {
    shapes.add(0, new Rectangle());
}
```

Works fine, as Rectangle is a shape, and shapes can now contain *any* shape.

**What is the strategy to make this work?**

Keeping your restriction of "PS: The class definition has to retain the ?." I see no way of making it work, aside from explicit casting.

As long as the class definition contains a wildcard, you can never be sure of what type it is. Which is also the reason why they [cannot be used as type parameters of classes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421639/can-we-use-wildcards-at-class-level-in-java)

What you may be interested in, is just normal plain [Generic Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Comment: I'm happy to improve the answer if someone explains the downvote.